# Error de iteración al intentar solucionar matriz inversa usando Gauss-Jordan en python

Tags: python, matrices, matriz

Estoy realizando un código para realizar matrices inversas, el código genera una matriz identidad y la adjunta a la primera matriz, así mismo para imprimirlas las separa, luego durante la ejecución desarrolla las columnas inferiores sin problema, pero al llegar a la segunda parte para desarrollar las columnas superiores las iteraciones no llegan hasta A[0][1] para reemplazar A[0]:

```
#Esta es la matriz con la primera parte ya desarrollada:
A = [
    [1,     1/3,    1/3,    1/3,    0,              0],
    [0,     1,      10,     1,      -3,             0],
    [0,     0,      1,      1/5,    -1/10,      -1/10]
]


#Función para mostrar la matriz con espacios.
def mostrar():
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for x in range(len(A[i])):
            if x != len(A[i])-(len(A[i])/2):
                print("{:.3f}".format(A[i][x]), end="\t")
            else: print("| \t {:.3f}".format(A[i][x]), end="\t")
        print(" ")
    print(" ")


#Función para desarrollar segunda parte (columnas superiores.)
def col2(i):
    verificador = i
    uwu = len(A)-1
    while verificador != -len(A)-1:
        #print("verificador:", verificador, "len(A):", len(A))
        pivote = A[verificador][uwu]
        print("Cambiar columnas.")
        print("")
        print("range:",range(len(A[i])-1))
        for x in range(len(A[i])):
            print("x:",x)
            print("{} - ( {} * {} ) = {}".format(A[verificador][x], pivote, A[i+1][x], A[verificador][x] - pivote * A[i+1][x]))
            A[verificador][x] = A[verificador][x] - pivote * A[i+1][x]
            mostrar()
        verificador -= 1
        uwu -= 1


for i in range(-2, -len(A)-1, -1):
    col2(i)


print("")
print("RESPUESTA:")
mostrar()
```

El output que me dá es este:

```
1.000   0.333   0.000   |    0.267  0.033   0.033    
0.000   1.000   0.000   |    -1.000 -2.000  1.000    
0.000   0.000   1.000   |    0.200  -0.100  -0.100
```

Pero el esperado es este:

```
1.000   0.000   0.000   |    0.600  0.700   -0.300   
0.000   1.000   0.000   |    -1.000 -2.000  1.000    
0.000   0.000   1.000   |    0.200  -0.100  -0.100
```

**La diferencia está en el A[0] pero no sé cómo solucionarlo, agradezco cualquier comentario o sugerencia.**

Gracias :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, ya encontré la solución.

El problema estaba aquí:

```
#Función para desarrollar segunda parte (columnas superiores.)
def col2(i):
    verificador = i
    uwu = len(A)-1
    while verificador != -len(A)-1:
        #print("verificador:", verificador, "len(A):", len(A))
        pivote = A[verificador][uwu]
        print("Cambiar columnas.")
        print("")
        print("range:",range(len(A[i])-1))
        for x in range(len(A[i])):
            print("x:",x)
            print("{} - ( {} * {} ) = {}".format(A[verificador][x], pivote, A[i+1][x], A[verificador][x] - pivote * A[i+1][x]))
            A[verificador][x] = A[verificador][x] - pivote * A[i+1][x]
            mostrar()
        verificador -= 1
        uwu -= 1


for i in range(-2, -len(A)-1, -1):
    col2(i)
```

Que reemplazamos a:

```
def col2(i):
    verificador = i
    while verificador != -len(A)-1:
        pivote = A[verificador][uwu]
        print("verificador:", verificador,"i:",i, "uwu:",uwu, "pivote:",pivote, "len(A):", len(A))
        print("Cambiar columnas.")
        print("")
        for x in range(-len(A[i]), 0):
            var1 = A[verificador][x]
            var2 = pivote
            var3 = A[i+1][x]
            var4 = var1 - (var2 * var3)
            print("{} - ( {} * {} ) = {}".format(var1, var2, var3, var4))
            A[verificador][x] = var4
            mostrar()
        #print("uwu")
        verificador -= 1

uwu = len(A)
print("!!!uwu:",uwu)
for i in range(-2, -len(A)-1, -1):
    uwu -= 1
    col2(i)
```

Esa sería la solución, crear una variable que itere fuera de la función para poder mover las columnas independientemente de `for i in range(-2, -len(A)-1, -1):`.